# Use resolve on route in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am hoping someone can help me. I need to wait until my data is loaded before showing the view. My plan is to use a resolve in the route but I can't seem to figure it out.

Route:

```
.when('/profile', {
    title: 'Profile',
    templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
    controller: 'profileCtrl',
    requiresAuthentication: true
})
```

Controller: (simplified for this post)

```
app.controller('profileCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $http, $timeout, Data, Auth, dataShare, $sessionStorage, $rootScope, $confirm) {
    $timeout(function() {

      Data.get('profile/'+$rootScope.user.uid).then(function(data){
        $scope.profs = data.data;
        $scope.buttonText = 'Update Profile';
      });

    }, 100);
});
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Will this post help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459262/angular-route-resolve-calling-a-service

Comment: I don't think so. I think I need to change my data retrieval in my controller to handle a promise but I am not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I am trying here. Haven't really used this feature much myself, about time I learn though. I've created a plunker with a sample, grabbing data from this question via SO's API.

In a nutshell, you have to set resolve as in the code snippet below. Each object in resolve must be a $promise to be able to prevent navigation before data is loaded, as found with Angular's $q. If the promise isn't "resolved", then navigation will not occur. A resolved promise in this case means that the request was a success. If the object is not a promise, then the routing will continue regardless of success/failure.

You will see if you go to 'won't work', the view never loads. This is because the URL provided to $http is bad, so the promise has not resolved there.

https://plnkr.co/edit/IyP1Myt6ewzju4eU6TaT?p=preview

The resolve function is in this piece of the code:

```
  when('/loaddata', {
    templateUrl: 'load_data.html',
    controller: 'LoadDataCtrl',
    resolve: {
      stackQuestion: function($http){
        // We must return something with a promise. $http already does that, so does $resource.
        // See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/37491743?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow'
        })
      }
    }
  }).
```

It is a start; it will do what you want I believe, but it is not handling errors yet.

**References**

- $q: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
- $http: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
- $routeProvider: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: Any chance you can help me apply this using my code?

Comment: I can try; is there any way you can start a demo on plunker like I have created with the code? We can use the API I did temporarily if your data source is not openly accessible.

Comment: I am trying to create a plunker that works but so far I can't get the routing to function in plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/LgUK8HsZxIeD6qSJMhAT?p=preview

Comment: Add <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular-route.js"></script> after the angular.js script tag